# IOS how to segue an array to another view controller

Tags: ios, arrays, view, controller, segue

I have an one initial view controller(A) and one navigation controller link to another view controller(B). How do i pass in the array from A to Big through segue?

This is my code for the segue.

```
  -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"severityInfo"]) {
        UINavigationController *segueNavigation = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSLog(@"%@",[[segueNavigation viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0]);
        IncidentOverviewViewController *B = (IncidentOverviewViewController *)[[segueNavigation viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
        B.BArray = feeds;
    }
}
```

I have this error after running this code: reason: '-reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'severityInfo'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

I have declare the method in my second view controller(incident view controller) which looks like this:

```
-(void)setFeeds:(NSMutableArray*)received
{
    BArray = received;

    NSLog(@"feeds are%@", BArray);

}
```

I have insert the identifier in the storyboard for the segue from my initial view controller call "view controller" this initial view controller is connected to a navigation view controller then from the navigation view controller connection to my destination view controller call "incidentOverviewViewController"

Comment: and what seems to be the problem in this code?

Comment: [IncidentOverviewViewController setBArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faf025bbf40'
This the error after i use the above codes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
  -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"severityInfo"]) {
        UINavigationController *segueNavigation = [segue destinationViewController];
       NSLog(@"%@",[[segueNavigation viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0]);
        IncidentViewControllerClassName *B = (IncidentViewControllerClassName *)[[segueNavigation viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
        B.BArray = feeds;
    }
}
```

And in the IncidentViewControllerClassName.h file

```
 @property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray *BArray;
```

To operate Push segue you need to Embedd a navigation controller to the View Controller From which you are segueing to another View Controller.
So embedd your First VC in a Navigation Controller.
Your storyboard should look like this

NavController -->(RootVC)--->VC1 (segue:severityInfo)---NavigationControlelr--(root)VC2.

Hope could make you understanding why the error is persisting.
To clear it off, Embedd VC1 or the view controller you are pushing from as the Root VC of a Navigation controller.

Comment: destination view controller of segue is navigation controller not the second view controller.

Comment: The error now is reason: '-[UINavigationController setBArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc38e019600'

Comment: i want to pass to my second view controller which is incidentViewController. Not passing the data to navigation view controller. how to do that?

Comment: Please check the EDIT, I have tested it myself and it is working as per your given architecture of the storyboard

Comment: Please check the Edit

Comment: There is this error: reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'severityInfo'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

Comment: I have inserted the segue identifier that is connected from my initial view controller to the navigation controller as severityInfo but why is Xcode giving me this error? The navigation controller is link to my destination controller call "incidentOverviewViewController"

Comment: Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'severityInfo'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

Comment: it shouldnt give the error now, i have created a demo and can upload it to you, if you desire it.

Comment: You are not following the Segue rules and implementing the Segue itself, i have edited for your understanding.

Comment: can email to me? crimson_sabre@hotmail.com

Comment: doing so, please wait 2 mins

Comment: did not receive your email. You sure email the correct one? crimson_sabre@hotmail.com

Comment: Yes i did sent the mail please check once agai.

Comment: what is the subject of your email?

Comment: StackOverFlow question Demo

Answer (score 0):

This is how this is done

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"severityInfo"]) {
        UINavigationController *segueNavigation = [segue destinationViewController];
        ViewController *B = (ViewController *)[segueNavigation topViewController];
        [B setBArray:feeds];

    }
}
```

Comment: There is this error: [IncidentOverviewViewController setBArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faf025bbf40'
Do i need to declare "setBarray" in the destination view controller(IncidentOverviewViewController) as well ? how it is going to be done if needed?

Comment: The ViewController is intended to be the rootViewController of UINavigationController you are trying to push, so if your rootViewController for UINavigationController is "IncidentOverviewViewController", then replace "ViewController" with that, and you need to make a property for bArray in "IncidentOverviewViewController" or whatever the root view controller is

Comment: ok, current my first view controller is call "view controller' , followed by my navigation controller then followed by incidentoverviewcontroller. Total there are 3 view controller. The segue i link as a push from "view controller" to navigation controller. So now the question is the code for ViewController *B should be incidentOverviewController *B or ViewController *B?

Comment: incidentOverviewController

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to define the method in the view controller you are calling. How else could you call it? You define the method as any other method.

You should also cast it to the `IncidentOverviewViewController`, if that is the type, not into `ViewController`.

Method will be something like this

```
-(void)setBArray:(whatevertype)array
{
    Dowhatever
}
```

Depending on your types and storage methods.

Comment: Yes, and how to define the method in incidentoverviewcontroller? what to import and declared?

Comment: @zac I am baffled. You haven't declared a single method before but are doing segues etc?

Comment: See the above codes. i have declare my method in my destination view controller call incidentOverviewController.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array as a property in your B view controller and in the segue method do following:-

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"severityInfo"])
    UINavigationController *segueNavigation = [segue destinationViewController];
    ViewController *B = (ViewController *)[segueNavigation topViewController];
    B.array = feeds;
}
```

Comment: this code ViewController *B = (ViewController *)[segueNavigation topViewController];  The "ViewController" is referring to the first viewController or the second view controller? if is the second view controller there is this error saying that the segue name "severityInfo" is not found.

Comment: View Controller is basically your "IncidentOverviewViewController" .So change this. Also please cross check if you have created the segue from A To B name "severityInfo"